# Agda type checker rejecting simple definition of a semigroup

Tags: agda, semigroup

I have defined a `Semigroup` as follows:

```
record Semigroup : Set1 where
    field
        X : Set
        e : X
        _◇_  :  X -> X -> X
        assoc : ∀ {x y z} -> (x ◇ y) ◇ z -> x ◇ (y ◇ z)
```

But I get the following error:

```
X should be a sort, but it isn't
when checking that the expression (x ◇ y) ◇ z has type _52
```

Can anyone help me determine what's wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to write `(x ◇ y) ◇ z ≡ x ◇ (y ◇ z)`?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the problem was that `(x ◇ y) ◇ z` and `x ◇ (y ◇ z)` were of type `X` and Agda was expecting them to be of type `Set`. This code works:

```
record Semigroup {X} (_≈_ : Rel X): Set1 where
    field
        e : X
        _◇_  :  X -> X -> X
        equivalence : Equivalence _≈_
        assoc : ∀ {x y z} -> ((x ◇ y) ◇ z) ≈ (x ◇ (y ◇ z))
```